# Javascript error "Cannot convert m to object" on Opera browser

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, web, mootools

I am working on my website and testing it on localhost WAMP server. I have included a javascript on my home page for displaying sliding facebook likebox (using mootools framework). The javascript is working fine on Chrome, Firefox, IE9. However, I can't see the slide box on Opera.

I tried to debug the error after adding my javascript folder (Preferences -> Content -> Javascript options) and I am getting the following error. (I can see the sliding facebook likebox once I include the javascript file from my local drive to Opera content extension, but still I can't figure out the problem.)

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'm' to object
Error thrown at line 1, column 47082 in <anonymous function: bottom>(n, m) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js:
    m.appendChild(n);
called from line 1, column 51362 in <anonymous function: inject>(n, m) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js:
    a[m||"bottom"](this,document.id(n,true));
called from line 19, column 1 in <anonymous function: FBSideLike.init>() in http://localhost/Demola_Template/media/js/fb-sidelike.js:
    var box = new Element('div', {
```

This is my javascript looks like and calling mootools-yui-compressed.js

```
var FBSideLike = {};

FBSideLike.init = function() {

    var scr = $$('script[fbpage]');

    if (scr.length == 1) {
        scr = scr[0];
        var fbpage = scr.get('fbpage');
    } else {
        return;
    }

    var border = scr.get('bordercolor') || '3b5997';
    var image  = scr.get('image') || 'plain';
    var base   = scr.get('src').replace('fb-sidelike.js', '');

    var box = new Element('div', {
        id: 'fb-side-like',
        styles: {
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + base + 'fb-sidebar-' + image + '.png)',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '12%',
            right: -292,
            width: 322,
            height: 200
        }
    }).inject(document.body);

    var like = new Element('div', {
        styles: {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 30,
            width: 292,
            height: 480,
            background: '#FFF'
        }
    }).inject(box);

    var toggle = function(dir) {
        box.tween('right', dir < 0 ? -1 : -292);
    }

    like.set('html', '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F'
                    + fbpage
                    + '&amp;width=292&amp;height=480&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=grey'
                    + border
                    + '&amp;stream=true&amp;header=false&amp;appId=************"'
                    + 'scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:480px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');

    box.set('tween', {
        duration: 550,
        transition: Fx.Transitions.Pow.easeInOut
    }).addEvents({
        'mouseenter': function() { toggle(-1); },
        'mouseleave': function() { toggle(1); }
    });
}

if (typeof(MooTools) == 'undefined') {
    (function() {
        var mt = document.createElement("script");
        mt.type = "text/javascript";
        mt.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http") + "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js";
        mt.async = true;
        mt.onload = FBSideLike.init;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(mt, s);
    })();
} else {
    window.addEvent('load', FBSideLike.init);
}
```

On my home page I have included the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/fb-sidelike.js" fbpage='*******'></script>
```

Looking at the error message it looks like the problem is in mootools-yui-compressed.js javascript file. However, I can't figure out what is going wrong, since it is working fine on every other browsers. Is this a browser specific problem or is there something I am missing.

Comment: There is bug with this version of mootools detailed in this [Blog Post](http://mootools.net/blog/2013/02/19/mootools-1-2-6-released/). Have you tried upgrade to the new 1.2.6 version ? [1.2.6](http://mootools.net/download/version/1.2.6)

Comment: What's the value of `typeOf(document.body)`? `document.id(document.body,true)` seems to return `null` for you

Comment: I hate sometimes when the code starts working using hit and trial method and I don't know the logic behind this. The opera browser problem is solved now. Initially in my html file, I included the script tag to include the javascript right below the head tag before opening the body tag. Shifting the script tag to bottom of my page above the closing body tag solves the problem, but I don't know how it worked.

Comment: You did call the function before the DOM was loaded - the parser did not encounter the `<body>` tag and therefore there was no `document.body` element yet (or at least it was `null`).